# Anchor control in Literal

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        public void Download(object obj, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("abc");
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Literal1.Text = "<a id='anc' href ='#' runat='server' onserverclick='Download'>Click Me</a>";
            Response.Write(Literal1.Text);

        }
    }
}

 <div>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
 </div>
```

I have the above code sniplet. I am trying to bind the anchor within the literal to a function in a following manner:  onserverclick = "Download"

But the event is not firing. The requirement is that anchor is rendered through literal only.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using anchor tag outside literal. Then it works fine

Answer (score 2):

While your `Literal1` control is a server-side control, setting the .Text value to represent a server control will not work.

Perhaps use the asp [`LinkButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) control instead of a literal

so your .aspx page would have:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="abc" runat="server" OnClick="Download" Text="Download" />
```

and your code behind .aspx.cs something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Download(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("abc");
}
```

Comment: No, we have the anchor tags in literal. So the parent will always be literal and it cannot be linkbutton.

Comment: @Pankaj your requirements to use a literal control and not use a webservice make this task unlikely to work without changing one of those two criteria

Comment: Corrective action is to use the anchor tag because we do not have to change the control. and not it is outside the literal. We got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute runat="server" is meaningless in the client-side code (which is what you're generating here). You may need to resort to calling a webservice.

Comment: No, we simply want to execute server side event on click of this anchor without using web service.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to use a LinkButton, you could replace your Literal with the text which you are adding to it on Page_Load (not entirely sure why youre doing it this way anyway?).

And then run an AJAX web request to run the Download method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply:). But we have already got the solution.